# Converting JS format to Createddate compatible format

Tags: apex

I have a JS date format as 
Mon May 16 2016 11:49:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

How can I convert that to date format in Salesforce . 
For e.g it should be compatible with createddate

Comment: how are you passing the JS date to apex? `actionFunction` or `Remote Action`?

Comment: @Praveen Remote Action

Answer (score 1):

```
j$('[Id$=theTextfrom]').datepicker({
            showOn:'both',                  
            buttonImage:"http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
            numberOfMonths:2,
            minDate: 0 
        });
```

using javaScript you can create date format like this. it will work for standard salesforce date fun

Comment: I would like to construct the current system date.  Can you help me with the format?

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert the JS Date to 'YYYY-MM-DD' string format as mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004680&),before sending it the remote action method.

In apex,convert the `String` to `Date`,using `Date.valueOf()` like this:

```
public static void method1(String dateStr){
    System.debug(Date.valueOf(dateStr));
}
```

If you are dealing with collection(Arrays,Objects),you need to covert the property which holds the JS Date to the above format,convert the JSON in apex as shown [here](http://blog.enree.co/2015/02/salesforce-remoteaction-using-date.html)

```
//Pass the date object,it returns the iso formatted date
function getSFISODateFormat(date){
    return date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDate() ;
}
```